# Deserialize dependent on field value

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I need to deserialize XML that uses a field "type" to indicate what content to expect.
Type 0 says that I can expect simple text whilst type 1 indicates that the content is of a more complex structure.

I know that I could write some custom deserialization mechanism but would like to know whether there was any builtin way to solve this.

Since the XMLSerializer expects a string it simply throws away the content in case it is XML. This stops me from running the content deserialization as a second step.

```
<Msg>
    <MsgType>0</MsgType>
    <Data>Some text</Data>
</Msg>

<Msg>
    <MsgType>1</MsgType>
    <Data>
        <Document>
            <Type>PDF</Type>
            .....
        </Document>
    </Data>
</Msg>
```

Comment: Type is a c# property so you can't use Type as a property name.  So with xml I use _Type and then add the xml attribute :  [XmlElement("Type")]string _Type { get;set;}

Comment: @jdweng um... yes you can. That's entirely legal. Not sure where you got that idea, to be honest. See example below which has `public string Type {get;set;}`

Comment: With a capital 'T' (not lowercase 't').  I should of wrote lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't supported out of the box; however, you could perhaps use:

```cs
public XmlNode Data {get;set;}
```

and run the "what to do with `Data`?" as a second step, once you can look at `MsgType`.

Complete example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string xml = @"<Foo>
<Msg>
    <MsgType>0</MsgType>
    <Data>Some text</Data>
</Msg>

<Msg>
    <MsgType>1</MsgType>
    <Data>
        <Document>
            <Type>PDF</Type>
            .....
        </Document>
    </Data>
</Msg>
</Foo>";
        var fooSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        var docSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
        var obj = (Foo)fooSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

        foreach (var msg in obj.Messages)
        {
            switch (msg.MessageType)
            {
                case 0:
                    var text = msg.Data.InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine($"text: {text}");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    var doc = (Document)docSerializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(msg.Data));
                    Console.WriteLine($"document of type: {doc.Type}");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("Msg")]
    public List<Message> Messages { get; } = new List<Message>();
}
public class Message
{
    [XmlElement("MsgType")]
    public int MessageType { get; set; }

    public XmlNode Data { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are a goddamn genius. Thanks a lot